# axios transformResponse returning undefined

Tags: javascript, axios, config

With the following I get the expected `response.data` value:

```
axios({
  method,
  url
}).then(response => { console.log(response) })
```

However, when I add the transformResponse property as follows I get a `response.data` value of `undefined`:

```
axios({
  method,
  url,
  transformResponse: [(data) => {
    return data
  }]
}).then(response => { console.log(response) })
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here! Thanks

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/576

Comment: Thanks anyone for taking the time to reply to this but I've swapped out axios for superagent and all's well. Not sure what was going on - felt like a bug but I can't imagine that something so basic wouldn't have been spotted before

Answer (score 4):

You can check the below sample to safe parse. `transformResponse` get data as raw staring so u can parse it.

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  transformResponse: [
    (data) => {
      let resp;
      try {
        resp = JSON.parse(data);
      } catch (error) {
        throw Error(
          `[requestClient] Error parsingJSON data - ${JSON.stringify(
            error
          )}`
        );
      }
      if (resp.status === "success") {
        return resp.data;
      } else {
        throw Error(`Request failed with reason -  ${data}`);
      }
    },
  ],
});
```

Else you can use an interceptor to simplify it.

```js
//const axios = require("axios");
const jsonInterceptor = [
  (response) => response.data,
  (error) => Promise.reject(error),
];
function jsonClient() {
  const client = axios.create();
  client.interceptors.response.use(...jsonInterceptor);
  return client;
}
// Page 1

const jhttp = jsonClient();
jhttp
  .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use interceptors since they are more clean

Interceptors work as a middlware on your requests

remove transformResponse and add this

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  return response.data;
});
```

```
axios({
  method,
  url,
}).then(response => { console.log(response) })
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering here is the response:

```
axios.get(url, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  transformResponse: axios.defaults.transformResponse.concat((data) => {
    console.log(data) // this should now be JSON
  })
})
```

from https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/430#issuecomment-243481806